# What software/toolkit should I use to manage/plan out a year-long trip across multiple countries?

Tags: open-source, ubuntu, finance, information-management, travel

In a few years I plan on traveling, pretty much all around the world. This is going to cost a good deal of money and be very complex, so I'm going to begin planning now.

What software/toolkit is the best choice to use for this? I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Now, I was going to use a combination of QGIS and a number of spreadsheets, but if there was any other solution you would recommend, I'm all for it.

My requirements are:

- Has to keep track of a number of physical locations, around the world.
- Has to store a lot of numbers: distances, money, gas prices, airline miles.
- Has to be updated frequently (currencies, airline tickets), preferably with a script.
- Must be password protected, and actual *encryption* (not just a password) would be a huge, **huge** bonus.
- Must be able to store/include multiple filetypes, such are PDF, DOC, XLS, etc.
- Must be able to export/download entire project for archiving on to disk.
- Must be still here in 4 years when I actually finish saving up.
- Must be open source.

Do you guys know anything that could fulfill, if not all, at least 4 out of those?  The password/encryption thing is really kind of a must, I'm going to be storing credit card numbers/plane tickets/routing numbers/my full name/my ssn in this project, plus there's the fact that I don't necessarily want people to know where I'm going.

Comment: Only planning? Will your print everything before leaving, or bring your laptop, or do you need synchronization with Android for instance?

Comment: I plan on bringing both a laptop and a smartphone.